# CSS Button effects not working across browsers

Tags: html, css, button, cross-browser

Having a few issues with a CSS Button effects not working across browsers.

It displays as I would like it in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Can't seem to find the root of the problem. Here is what I have.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/postcolonialboy/wn0y71zs/)

```css
a.soft {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 20px 0 #E6E6E6, 10px 10px 20px 0 #ABABAB, inset 10px 10px 20px 0 #E6E6E6, inset -10px -10px 20px 0 #ABABAB;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #666666;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0) 2px 2px 5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

a.soft:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 20px 0 #E6E6E6, 10px 10px 20px 0 #ABABAB, inset 10px 10px 20px 0 #E6E6E6, inset -10px -10px 20px 0 #ABABAB;
  color: #888;
}

a.soft:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #E6E6E6, 0 0 20px 0 #ABABAB, inset 0 0 20px 0 #E6E6E6, inset 0 0 20px 0 #ABABAB;
  color: #D8D8D8;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px white;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<a class="soft">Button</a>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to elaborate on what exactly is/is not working as expected, please? My first guess was that your problem was because you are using `-webkit-background-clip` without the regular `background-clip` anywhere, and Firefox isn't a Webkit browser (you need to use `mox-background-clip`), but actually when I open it in Firefox on my Mac, it seems the same as Chrome. Ironically, the only browser I see any hover action on between FF, Chrome, and Safari is FF, so it seems like it's the only one that *does* work to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a firefox specific rule which corrected everything.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  a.soft {
    background-color: #ddd;
    box-shadow: -10px -10px 20px 0 #E6E6E6,
      10px 10px 20px 0 #ABABAB,
      inset 10px 10px 20px 0 #E6E6E6,
      inset -10px -10px 20px 0 #ABABAB;
    color: #888;
  }
}
```